# Swift Converting PFQuery to String Array for TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to query all of the Parse users in my database and then display each individual user in their own cell in a tableview. I have set up my tableview, but I'm stuck on saving the user query to a string array that can be used within the tableview. I have created a `loadParseData` function that finds the objects in the background and then appends the objects queried to a string array. Unfortunately I am given an error message on the line where I append the data.

`Implicit user of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit'` This seems to me that it is suggestion that I use `self.` instead of `usersArray.` because this is within a closure, but I'm given another error if I run it that way, `*classname* does not have a member named 'append'`

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class SearchUsersRegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var userArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func loadParseData(){

        var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error != nil{

                println("\(objects.count) users are listed")

                for object in objects {

                    userArray.append(object.userArray as String)

                }
            }

        }

    }


    let textCellIdentifier = "Cell"

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return usersArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as SearchUsersRegistrationTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row

        //cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: usersArray[row])

        //cell.usernameLabel?.text = usersArray[row]

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that userArray is an NSArray. NSArray is immutable, meaning it can't be changed. Therefore it doesn't have an append function. What you want is an NSMutableArray, which can be changed and has an addObject function.

```
var userArray:NSMutableArray = []

func loadParseData(){
    var query : PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    self.userArray.addObject(object)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            println("There was an error")
        }
    }
}
```

Also, because objects are returned as 'AnyObject' you will have to cast them as PFUsers at some point in order to use them as such. Just something to keep in mind

**For getting the user's username and displaying it**

// Put this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
var user = userArray[indexPath.row] as! PFUser
var username = user.username as! String
cell.usernameLabel.text = username
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was extremely helpful, but I was wondering if you can help me with the object that needs to be casted in order to display the users in cells. I interpreted that as setting `cell.usernameLabel.text = userArray[row] as? PFUsers` but I am shown `cannot assign a value of type 'PFUser?' to a value of type 'String?'` Am I casting the wrong object?

Comment: A PFUser is a class -basically a dictionary- w/ different key/value pairs: email, username, etc... setting the text label to PFUser does not grab the username, it tries to use the entire PFUser which you can't do. You have to grab the PFUser's username property on your own. Try something like what i've added above.

Comment: I can't format that as a comment, I'll add it as an addition to my answer above.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a call to the `loadParseData` function in order to add the queried objects to the array?

Comment: yes, there should be, my mistake, I forgot to add that in there. Put self.tableView.reloadData() after the query is complete and you fill your userArray with users. I've edited my answer to show this